# Convert a list of Map to JSON objects using Stream API

Tags: json, java-stream

I am creating an API that takes in a JSON array of Map and it internally calls another API that expects the input as JSON objects. I am trying to do this conversion by streams API.

```
{
  "request":[
    {
      "key1":"first_name",
      "value1":"Merlin"
    },
    {
      "key2":"last_name",
      "value2":"Grey"
    },
    {
      "key3":"gender",
      "value3":"female"  
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
 "first_name":"Merlin",
 "last_name":"Grey",
 "gender":"female"
}
```

How do I do this using streams API ?

Comment: What have you tried? Include you attempt as well

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it completely with Streams API, but I've written a solution, and it's working

Considering you have stored the jsonArray with key "request" in a List "responseArr" of type List<Map<String, String>>

```
        
        Map<String,String> convertedResponseMap = responseArr.stream()
                 .map(MyClass::fetchMapEntry)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                entry -> entry.getKey(),
                entry ->  entry.getValue()
        ));
        System.out.println(convertedResponseMap );
```

Then the fetchMapEntry method creates a single entry with the logic you wanted

```
private static Map.Entry<String,String> fetchMapEntry(Map<String,String> map){

        List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());

        if(keys.get(0).startsWith("key"))
            return Map.entry(map.get(keys.get(0)),map.get(keys.get(1)));
        else
            return Map.entry(map.get(keys.get(1)),map.get(keys.get(0)));

    }
```